# Using third party npm library which using crypto in Expo

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, cryptojs

In our expo mobile application we need to install NPM package which have crypto dependency. Is it possible to replace that with expo-crypto library.

So that instead of NODE's inbuilt crypto library, can the third party NPM package start to use expo-crypto library without modifying source of code of the third party NPM package?

Comment: paste GitHub URL of that lib you wanted to use.

Comment: https://github.com/nemfoundation/symbol-hd-wallets/blob/master/package.json